# How deleteLater() actually works in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Barebones example:

```
Object * o = new Object(); //let's call this one object A on heap
o->deleteLater();
o = new Object(); //and let's call this one object B on heap
```

Is deleteLater() going to delete A or B when we enter the event loop? I guess my question is, does deleteLater() make a copy of the pointer at the point of calling or does it delete whatever pointer holds when entering the event loop?

If the latter is true, how can we deleteLater() a pointer which we need to reinitialize?

Comment: This is simple to test... print a message from the destructor of `Object` with the address of the object, and compare it to the addresses of `A` and `B` on construction (or add an identifier to the object and print that, etc...)

Comment: Ok I tried this, apparently the original is removed. So I guess it makes a temporary pointer to the object?

Comment: Yeah - it's storing the address of the object to remove. Qt doesn't care what *you* have named it (i.e. what you do with your pointer after the call to deleteLater).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QObject::deleteLater()` is just a plain method of QObject. You cannot call a method on a pointer, only on the object the pointer points to. So deleteLater() operates on the object the pointer variable `o` is pointing to (`*o`) at the time you call deleteLater(). It cannot know about the local pointer variable you're using (`o`), which is your private business.

To share the actual pointer variable, it would be necessary to pass it somewhere via a QObject** (pointer to QObject pointer;`&o`), which you don't.

In QObject::deleteLater(), the method refers to the object it's called on via the `this` pointer, independent of any other variables  that refer to the same object (such as `o`).

Answer (score 3):

Basically it just doing `QCoreApplication::postEvent` with event of type `deferredDelete` and your `QObject` as a receiver and when this event is finally dispatched to aforementioned `QObject` there is just function which is basically doing `delete this`.

So pointer to your object happily lives inside the event as it's receiver.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the answer of Predelnik:

basically `deleteLater()` does it the same way as `garbage collection` does. It is not 100% clear when the deletion happens, but it says that it will be deleted in the `event loop` with low priority.

So it does kind of everything else and when there is time it will delete your object and ensure every signal/slot stuff is made and the object is save to delete.
And it is the prefered way to delete `QObject`'s cause you cannot have problems with callbacks.

cheers